# When will Weblogic Server support Java EE 8?

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c, java-ee-8

Other than a reference [here](https://community.oracle.com/blogs/mnemonic/2018/01/12/oracle-weblogic-and-java-cloud-service-roadmap) to CY2018.. I'm finding it eerily difficult to figure out when (or if) a Weblogic Server release will support Java EE 8?

Comment: If I remember correctly JEE7 was out a couple of years before weblogic supported it. I wouldn't expect it any time soon.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like there has been some movement at Oracle for a new release lately. In September 2019 they have annouced the "[Weblogic Server 14 Beta Programm](https://blogs.oracle.com/weblogicserver/announcing-the-oracle-weblogic-server-and-oracle-coherence-1411-beta-program)", since Version 13 will be skipped. Therefore the development of the new version comes to a close. As stated in the post from Oracle, the new release will support Java EE 8 an Jakarta EE 8 as well as Java SE 11.

Still they did not announced a release date, so time will tell how long the beta programm will last.

**Edit 03/2020:** Oracle has now officially release Weblogic 14 with Java EE 8 Support: https://blogs.oracle.com/weblogicserver/announcing-oracle-weblogic-server-1411